# How many ways are there to convert and pass stdin as command parameter?

Tags: pipe, xargs

I am new to Linux shell. I know that `xargs` can be used to accept stdin from a pipe and pass it to another command as parameter. Are there other ways to do so? Is there a list I can refer to? A non-exhaustive list I can find:

1. `echo $PATH | xargs echo`
2. `echo $(echo $PATH)`
3. `` echo `echo $PATH` ``
4. `echo $PATH | while read -r line; do echo $line; done;` (Thanks to @Tom Hunt)

Anyting else?

Comment: Usually `xargs` is what you want for that application. It has quite a few options you can use to tweak the precise output, for which see `man xargs`. If you need to do something which `xargs` can't handle directly, you can also pipe your output into a shell loop, using something like `some_command | while read -r line; do some_other_command $line; done`.